# Trigger a helpful error if I provide a wrongly named argument

Tags: r, error-handling, ellipsis

When writing a function including a `...` argument, making a mistake
in an argument name will not trigger an error immediately.
it's especially annoying when we forget to "dot" an argument

```
addxy <- function(..., .x, .y, .z){
  .x + .y
}

addxy(.x=1,.y=2)
# [1] 3
addxy(.x=1,y=2)
# Error in addxy(.x = 1, y = 2) : argument ".y" is missing, with no default
```

In a real situation the error might be less explicit, and `y` might be a valid
input or not so I can't dismiss it from the start.

How can I give a friendly error in this case to help the user correct their call ?

Comment: It's possible that I didn't word the question perfectly as I started from the answer I might not have a clear mind, any feedback appreciated (or downvote away, no hard feelings! :D)

Answer (score 1):

We can wrap the function call in `try` and then if it fails, do some
gymnastics to get analyse the original call and the formals and determine what
might have gone wrong.

Putting it all in one function we get :

```
with_friendly_dot_error <- function(fun){
  fiendly_fun <- fun
  body(fiendly_fun) <- substitute({
    MC <- match.call()
    MC[[1]] <- quote(fun)
    res <- try(eval.parent(MC),silent = TRUE)
    if(inherits(res,"try-error")){
      frmls <- setdiff(names(formals()),"...")
      dot_names <- names(eval(substitute(alist(...))))
      candidates <- intersect(paste0(".",dot_names), frmls)
      stop(attr(res,"condition")$message,
           "\nDid you forget the dots in argument(s): ",
           paste0(candidates, collapse = ", ")," ?")
    }
    res
  })
  fiendly_fun
}
```

Works normally when no error :

```
with_friendly_dot_error(addxy)(.x=1,.y=2)
# [1] 3
```

Gives helpful error when relevant :

```
with_friendly_dot_error(addxy)(.x=1, y=2)
# Error in with_friendly_dot_error(addxy)(.x = 1, y = 2) : 
#   argument ".y" is missing, with no default
# Did you forget the dots in argument(s): .y ?
```